# custom font on text inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a custom font which I need to use inside

> project/assets/fonts/font.ttf

The css file is inside

> project/css/style.css

The html snippet is:

```
<div class="text"> title </div>
```

The css part is:

```
.text{
width: 33.3%;
float:left;
font-family:font;
src: url('../assets/fonts/font.ttf');}
```

But this is not working. That is, the text is being displayed with default font. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Is this just an example? There is not a font called font.ttf

Comment: @Mike OP is trying to declare his/her font file `font.ttf` as a new font by using `src`, and naming it `font`.

Answer (score 5):

First off, you may want to consider using one of the many `.ttf` to `.woff`converters online, as `.woff` is a more web-friendly format.

Second, you'll need to declare the font before you start using it. That can be done in CSS like so:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url('../assets/fonts/font.ttf');
}

.text {
    width: 33.3%;
    float:left;
    font-family: myFont;
}
```

---

Regarding the `.woff` suggestion:

> WOFF is a font format for use in web pages. It was developed in 2009, and is now a W3C Recommendation. WOFF is essentially OpenType or TrueType with compression and additional metadata. The goal is to support font distribution from a server to a client over a network with bandwidth constraints.

Source: [w3schools - CSS3 Web Fonts](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You're including the font the wrong way, use [`@fontface`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: testFont;
  src: url('../assets/fonts/font.ttf');
}
```

Then just use the font like you would any other:

```
.text{
  width: 33.3%;
  float:left;
  font-family: testFont;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to import this font inside your CSS using **[@font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)**, like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyFont;
  src: url('myfont.ttf');
}
```

And then use it as a font in your elements, like:

```
.text{
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  font-family: MyFont;
}
```

Hope this helps!